# Adding a clickable URL to my Cocoa view - am I doing it wrong?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsattributedstring

I need to dynamically set the text and value for a clickable URL in my view.

I've got it working using an `NSTextView`, but it seems ridiculously complicated to set the font and I can't figure out how to center the text:

```
NSMutableAttributedString* attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Click me"
                                                                               attributes:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Lucida Grande" size:14], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];
[attrString beginEditing];
[attrString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:@"http://example.com" range:NSMakeRange(0, [attrString length])];
[attrString endEditing];
[[self.downloadLinkTextField textStorage] setAttributedString:attrString];
```

1. Am I doing it wrong? I can't find anything in the Object Library for URLs.
2. Is it possible to center align the link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've done it correctly. Apple has a [handy writeup about this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1487/_index.html) which provides a `Hyperlink` category on `NSAttributedString` that you can use if you're so inclined. Their category also underlines and colorizes the link text.

As for centering, that's a function of the view, and not the text itself. You can use [`-[NSText alignCenter:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000367-alignCenter_) (`NSText` is the superclass of `NSTextView`), after you have selected your string using [`setSelectedRange:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000367-setSelectedRange_), or if you want all the text in the view to be centered, just use:

```
[myTextView setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment];
```

Answer (score 1):

There is something very important missing in this thread:

after begin/end editing of the attributed string and 
before setting the attributed string...

you need to call the following on your textfield or the link will not work:

```
[self.downloadLinkTextField setAllowsEditingTextAttributes:YES];
[self.downloadLinkTextField setSelectable:YES];
```

I received this information from [here](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/358-how-to-make-a-clickable-link-inside-a-nstextfield-and-cocoa)

glhf!
-eric